# How to position AmCharts 5 X-Axis label to the right?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I've added a x-axis label to my bar chart, but i would like it to be next to the x-axis, not at the bottom.

This is what i have now:

[image: AM5 how it is now]

But i would like it to be like this:
[image: What i want AM5]

What i've tried:

```js
xAxis.children.push(
      am5.Label.new(root, {
          text: "ETD",
          textAlign: 'right',
          x: am5.p100,
          fontSize: 11,
      })
);
```

I've also tried something along the lines of this: [AM4 Titles on top of vertical axis](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/titles-on-top-of-vertical-value-axis/) using paddingRight in AM5. Sadly without result.

I've also tried some options from [this AM5 list](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/axis/), but also found no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in place of you old xAxis.children.push.

```
xAxis.children.push(
      am5.Label.new(root, {
          text: "ETD",
          textAlign: 'right',
          x: am5.percent(105),
          y: am5.percent(-30),
          fontSize: 11,
      })
);
```

You can adjust the Text by change this x and y percent.